# Logstash is not exposing port 5044 in Docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, logstash

I'm having troubles with Logstash with Docker.

I'm using docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.5.1.
The problem is that the container is not exposing port 5044, despite that the docker-compose is exposing that given port.

```
services:
  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.5.1
    ports: ['5044:5044']
    expose:
      - '5044'
```

Tried around 5 hours but can't understand where is the problem.
The way that I'm trying to figure out if the port is being exposed by container is using **nmap localhost** and **docker container ls** (and looking at the PORTS section). I'm in a MacOS machine.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is related to loopback addresses, you can see more info here https://discuss.elastic.co/t/docker-image-doesnt-expose-ports-in-custom-image/156479/4

Answer (score 0):

did you check if the host machine port is in use or not :  netstat -plntu and look for that port else you can change it on host by some other port like 
port: ['5045:5044']
expose:
 - '5044'
And up your app and check if it's working or not?

Comment: This is the output of **docker container ls**: a6107e71c4af        docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.5.1   "/usr/local/bin/dock…"   8 hours ago         Up 8 hours          0.0.0.0:5044->5044/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9600->9600/tcp   monitoring-nginx_logstash_1_89def55b7810